Microsoft Graph API to get real time perf metrics (CPU, RAM, Disk) of Windows 365 (Cloud PCs)
Below PowerShell script is using Microsoft Graph apis to pull historic data related to W365 Cloud PCs. Similarly, we need to monitor real time performance metrics (CPU, RAM, Disk) of W365 Cloud PCs. Are there any apis or PowerShell commands to fetch these parameters?
The sample script we use to get CPU, RAM spike time percentage:
$clientId = ''
$clientSecret = ''
$tenantId = ''

$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($tenantId)"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$apiVersion = "beta"
$objs = @()
$outputs = @()
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolTYpe]::Tls12

# Authenticate and acquire access token
$tokenEndpoint = "$authority/oauth2/token"
$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    resource      = $resource
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Method POST -Body $body

# Get access token from the response
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

# Define the API endpoint
$apiEndpoint ="https://graph.microsoft.com/$($apiVersion)/deviceManagement/userExperienceAnalyticsResourcePerformance"

#$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $($accessToken)"}
<# $headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $($accessToken)"
              "Content-Type" = "application/json" } #>
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $($accessToken)"
              Accept = "application/json" }

$apiResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiEndpoint -Method Get -Headers $headers #-ContentType "application/json"
$outputs = $apiResponse.Value | Select deviceName,model,cpuSpikeTimePercentage,ramSpikeTimePercentage,cpuSpikeTimeScore,ramSpikeTimeScore,deviceResourcePerformanceScore,averageSpikeTimeScore

